# ppc avd manager and android sdk

Tags: android, sdk, emulation, powerpc

I have a non Intel PowerPC G5 running 10.5.8. I downloaded Eclipse and installed Android SDK and tools and also installed a plugin using "install software" in the help sectionof eclipse.

I have the latest sdk and tools and attempted to use the command line to correct this error I 
receive when clicking "android" in the tools folder of adt bundle- mac for x86_64

"users-imac-g5-2:~ owner1$ /Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/tools/android ; exit;
SWT folder '/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/tools/lib/ppc' does not exist.
Please export ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
logout

[Process completed]

Now, I downloaded Soylatte. I am unable to start the emulator, AVD and would like to know what command I need to use to get swt_jar connected to ANDROID_SWT

Or is this a Java issue and I need to install an older Android SDK?

When I go in to the SDK and click one of the emulators.
I get this
**Last login: Tue Feb  5 00:49:38 on ttys000
/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86 ; exit;
users-imac-g5-2:~ owner1$ /Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86 ; exit;
-bash: /Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86: Bad CPU type in executable
logout**

[Process completed

Comment: The Android SDK only supports x86 and x86-64.

Answer (score 1):

You are installing software intended for a different architecture (x86_64) which is incompatible with PowerPC and thus it won't work.